# Lightning component String.length not the same as what the custom field gives as length

Tags: lightning-aura-components, custom-field, long-text-area

I'm working on a lightning component which stores it's data to a Salesforce Long Text Area custom field of size 600 on the Account object. In the component, we have an html text area, upon each keyup, we udate the character count. So we display the amount of characters left out of 600. We use the standard length method of javascript. The count goes from 600 down to 0 as expected. Once it's saved to the custom field, if I edit that field in account layout directly and save it without changing anything, it says that I'm 5 characters above the limit. We don't add anything to the string or convert anything when we save it. Is this a known issue? Are there any ways to fix this? I tried pretty much everything I could find on getting an accurate character count, nothing worked. I don't know where the 5 extra characters come from in SF.

Comment: Does the text you're working with include any non-Roman or accented characters?

Comment: @DavidReed No, it's all standard characters. And will only be standard characters.

Comment: Can you include some relevant code we can use to recreate the issue in a developer org?

Comment: @DavidReed Sorry it took me a while to answer. We decided to put this issue on the back burner for now and go forward with the solution as is. I'll try to post the code over the weekend.

Comment: It's looks like its a problem with the new lines. I'm having the same problem here, Aura/Javascript treats new lines as just one characters and let's us save to Salesforce, but after it's saved Salesforce standard ui treats new lines as 2 characters and fails the update